# Which library to use for uploading a excel file with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very basic JS and React question I suppose, but I am new to this so thank you for any help!

I would like to upload an excel file via a form and  and then access the data in the columns and rows and for example calculate the average for the data in the first columns. How should I proceed to do that in the frontend?

Comment: Are you asking about *uploading* the Excel file (i.e. sending it to a server) or *reading it locally* (i.e. with client-side JS inside the browser). Or both? (In which case you should narrow the focus of the question). Note also that questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin , I would like to read it locally inside the browser and get the calculation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xlsx.js for reading excel files and convert them into json object and then you can simply proceed with the data and do all your calculations.

This is how it is done in normal html files.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
var ExcelToJSON = function() {

  this.parseExcel = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
      });

      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        // Here is your object
        var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
        console.log(json_object);

      })

    };

    reader.onerror = function(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };
};
</script>
```

You can do the same by importing the links directly into your react component.

```js
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js";
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js";
...
```